# Sonata one to many relationship

Tags: symfony, relationship, one-to-many, sonata-admin, sonata

I'm a beginner with sonata and I don't understand how can I do `choicetype` in one to many (dropdown list) with 2 tables `Oraganizations`(one) and  `structures_type`(many).
I've find nothing in sonata doc. I use sonata 2.3 and symfony 2.8.
if someone can help me to resolve this problem. here is the code:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
   $formMapper
           ->add('structurestypes', EntityType::class, array(
               'class' => 'HandissimoBundle:StucturesTypes',
               'choice_label' => 'structurestype',
               'label' => 'Type de structure',
               'expanded' => true,
               'multiple' => true,
               'by_reference' => true
           ));
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as with any other Symfony form. Check this page: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Answer (score 1):

A dropdown list appears if you simply set the 'expanded' attribute to false or remove it, because the default value is false.